# cyclic groups -class is prime number

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How can I prove that a group $G$, such that $|G| = p$, where $p \in \mathbb{P}$, 
is cyclic?

Comment: What's your definition of $\;G_p\;$ , for $\;p\;$ a prime??

Comment: G is a group which has p numbers or the class of group is p

Comment: "The class of group"  seems to be a non-standard, particular term. But "number of elements, or **order of the group**,  is easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\;G=\{g_1,...,g_p\}\;$ and let $\;1\neq g_i\in G\;$. Look at the cyclic subgroup $\;\langle\,g_i\,\rangle\,\le\,G\;$.

Now apply Lagrange's Theorem: what can you say of the order of that subgroup? And then...?

Answer (score 0):

Here |G| = p (prime). Consider a non-identity element 'a' of the group G. By Corollary of  Lagrange's Theorem, |a| divides |G|. So, |a| = p = |G| (Since, a ≠ e ). Thus, 'a' generates G. Hence we conclude that G is cyclic.